# How to get image path in eclipse rcp application

Tags: java

1> I am developing desktop application using eclipse rcp mail.

2> I have to display image from project path.

3> I get that image when i run project by click on that project.

4> but when i am creating exe of that project by exporting as a eclipse project and run that exe at that time don't get that image.

Comment: You have to export the images too when you're making a release. Also adjust the code to get the absolute path of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you mentioned it was an RCP app?

Have you tried the following?

```
getClass().getResources("/whatever.png");
```